# How do I return nothing instead of a blank space in this if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

You can see I use "" to make the if statement return nothing in certain cases, but in reality it returns a blank space. I don't want that white space, what could I use instead?

```
if (n >= 20000 && n < 100000) {
        result = `${tens[Math.floor(n / 10000) - 1]} ${
            Math.floor((n % 10000) / 1000) != 0
                ? num[Math.floor((n % 10000) / 1000)]
                : ""
        } thousand ${n % 1000 != 0 ? number2words(n % 1000) : ""}`;

        return result.trim();
    }
```

Comment: you can return `null` or `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to restructure you code and move the include the space when the condition is truthy.

```
const tensText = tens[Math.floor(n / 10000) - 1];
const divisible = Math.floor((n % 10000) / 1000);
const hundredsText = divisible != 0 ? ` ${num[divisible]}` : '';
const thousandsText = n % 1000 != 0 ? ` ${number2words(n % 1000)}` : '';

result = `${tensText}${hundredsText} thousand${thousandsText}`;
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!

Comment: Might be much simpler to push the parts conditionally into an array then to `.join(' ')` them

Comment: You are welcome. @bergi, that is another good approach

Answer (score 0):

To return nothing, you'd use `return;`

However, if one case returns a string, you should probably always return a string for consistency.